# Can I use bold tag for two full sentences on my home page

Tags: html

I want to make the home page content which is two sentences around 50 words completely bold for readability. I am going to use the bold tag. How will it affect users and search engines?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes. You could make the whole website bold if you wanted. It makes no difference to search engines but users might get a bit confused. Like the website is yelling at them.**

Comment: (I can't believe I answered this)

Comment: It's my 2nd favourite SO question. Behind How can I unzip a file using CSS?

Comment: links or it didn't happen. :)

Comment: @RussellGutierrez - It was deleted even though I asked them to never remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Using “the bold tag”, which presumably means `b` element, will make the text less readable in most situations. To make text more prominent, increased font size generally works better than bolding. In classic typography, bolding is normally used only for headings and individual words in text.

There is no evidence of any effect on search engines, though an effect would not be completely illogical (search engines could give the content of `b` elements higher relative weight within the page).

Comment: <strong>welcome to the XXI</strong> ;)